# Optimizing the following code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I have two active records `StudentDemographics` and `StudentWeeklyReport` both having `has_many` relation like this:

```
class StudentDemographics < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_weekly_reports, :foreign_key => :student_id
end
```

I have to check marks for each student in the last fifth week seminar with the latest one. If the result is `true`, student should be active, else inactive. I have the following code. Here, I am repeating the loop with each date. `@distinct` is an array of dates.

```
 for i in 0...@distinct.length
     active = 0
     inactive = 0
     sum = safe.length
     @students = StudentDemographics.where("date <= ?", @distinct[i]).select("student_id") - safe
     @students.each do |student|
        @stu = StudentWeeklyReport.where(:student_id => student.student_id).select("student_id,golden_eggs").last(5)
            if @stu.length > 4
                if @stu[4].golden_eggs > @stu[0].golden_eggs
                  safe << student
                  active += 1
                else
                  inactive += 1
                end
            else
                safe << student
                active += 1
            end
      end
      @active[i] = active + sum
      @inactive[i] = inactive
end
```

The performance is not good. It's taking more than 3 secs of time.my mysql db having 13600 in `StudentWeeklyReports` table and 2000 in `StudentDemographics` table. Can anyone suggest how to optimize the following code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     @students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports) - safe
 for i in 0...@distinct.length
     active = inactive = 0
     @students.each do |student|
        next if student.date > @distinct[i]
        @stu = student.student_weekly_reports.select("golden_eggs").last(5)
            if @stu.length > 4 && (@stu[4].golden_eggs <= @stu[0].golden_eggs)
                inactive += 1
            else
                safe << student
                active += 1
            end
      end
      @active[i] = active + safe.length
      @inactive[i] = inactive
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Thaha kp. Your answer seems good but the response time got increased from 3 secs to 12 secs..it is printing some Explain commands in the console log.

Comment: @Thaha's solutions seems fine and it cannot be slower as compared to the loop you have posted in question. Thaha's solution will definetly be faster. Try running both the loops by restarting your server to see the actual difference between the two. Your loop may have taken 3 secs beacuse of ActiveRecord query caching which is being performed internally by rails.

Comment: Moreover  replacing `&&` with `and` will also help a bit, since && will check both the conditions while with `and` it will not check the second condition if first one is false.

Comment: @AmitThawait I agreed with you but when I am running the app with the above logic, In console it is printing the sql query ' SELECT `student_weekly_reports`.* FROM `student_weekly_reports` WHERE `student_weekly_reports`.`student_id` IN(more than 10000 records)' it is checking all the 13000 records every time...Is there any solution to avoid this...

Comment: Ohh.. you should just take this line out of the loop like : `@students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).where("date <= ?", @distinct.min).select("student_id")`. This line will give you all the data you want to fecth from your DB. Try the answer, I posted

Comment: Edited the answer.. Please try this

Answer (score 0):

```
@students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).where("date <= ?", @distinct.min).select("student_id")
# The above line will fetch all the necessary records you require 

for i in 0...@distinct.length
 active = inactive = 0
 @students = @student.select { |student_demographics| student_demographics.date <= @distinct[i] } - safe
 @students.each do |student|
   @stu = student.student_weekly_reports.select("golden_eggs").last(5)
   if @stu.length > 4 and (@stu[4].golden_eggs <= @stu[0].golden_eggs)
     inactive += 1
   else
     safe << student
     active += 1
   end
  end
  @active[i] = active + safe.length
  @inactive[i] = inactive
end
```

Comment: @Amit.. In loop we are getting weekly reports related to student by using this 'student.student_weekly_reports'...do we need to include student_weekly_report with student_demographics..? as like this 'StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).where("date <= ?", @distinct.min).select("student_id")'

Comment: Actually we are doing `eager_loading` using the line `@students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).where("date <= ?", @distinct.min)` means all the `student_weekly_reports` associated with each `StudentDemographics` record will be prefetced. So, no query will be fired while we are doing `student.student_weekly_reports`. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: I don't think so...Just try the same in rails console and you will see that it will not fire any query. In rails console first do : `@students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).where("date <= ?", some_date)` then try doing `@students.first.student_weekly_reports`, you will see that no quey is fired...

Comment: Yeah I got the thing ...the problem is with select in '@stu = student.student_weekly_reports.select("golden_eggs").last(5)'..rather than select this i did '@stu = student.student_weekly_reports.last(5)' which reduces response time much lesser...thank you so much @Amit..